# A regex that matches all text in a field but NOT hashtags

Tags: regex, hashtag

The title pretty much says it all:

I need a regular expression that matches all text in a field but NOT hashtags

UPDATE:

`\B#\w*[a-zA-Z]+\w*` Matches a hashtag

`/^(?:(?!PATTERN).)*$/`    # Matches strings not containing PATTERN

So, I tried to combine them both, but it does not work

```
/^(?:(?!\B#\w*[a-zA-Z]+\w*).)*$/
```

UPDATE:

Input: It's a sunny day in #Berlin

Output **It's a sunny day in** #Berlin

Comment: Sure you need it but have you made attempts to solve it?

Comment: @anubhava don't be too fast to close it. Check the update

Comment: Just to clarify neither I downvoted nor I clicked on close. I just left a comment asking for more info.

Comment: Also to clarify further it is better to place some example inputs and expected matches.

Comment: @user1107412 Can you provide some input and expected output ? Do you want to match lines/strings that do not contain hashtags ? Or do you want to skip the hashtag per string and match the rest of the string ? Also, what language are you using ? And sorry for being fast with closing questions, but it's just irritating to see so many questions that only defines requirements without any code in it. I hereby retract my vote.

Comment: @HamZa Input/Output added. The idea is exactly the opposite of finding the hashtags, which is easy. I need to find all the text which does not consist of hashtags

Comment: @user1107412 So what about `It's a sunny day in #Berlin and really hot` ? Should it match **It's a sunny day in** #Berlin and really hot or **It's a sunny day in** #Berlin **and really hot** ?

Comment: @HamZa everything that's not a hashtag. So, "and really hot" too. Also, the regex must be able to work with multiple hashtags

Comment: @user1107412 I'm in quite a hurry right now, if you're using PCRE (php for example) you might use `#\w+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|.*?(?=#\w+|$)` [demo](http://regex101.com/r/pB1sC7). If you're using something like JS then `(#\w+)|()(.+?)(?=#\w+|$)` and if you're using something like python then `(#\w+)|(.+?)(?=#\w+|$)`. Note that the python and JS solutions relies on groups. If you want the two sentences to be merged at the end, then just replace/remove the hashtag with something like `#\w+` (no complexity :P). Cyaa

Comment: What flavour of regex are you using?  What language are you using to process the regex results?  Regexes don't readily return strings with substrings removed - that's up to the language that processes the regex results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
((?:(?!#\w).)*)
```

**[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/qN5bI9)**

**Explanation :**

[image]

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SujithPS/8MKuK/)**

Comment: Does not match multiple hashtags: "It's a #nice sunny day in #Berlin #Germany" breaks the above demo